# If I upgrade my system will my desktop manager change to Unity?

Tags: release-management

I have an old Acer netbook which is running Lubuntu 14.10. I haven't used it in a while and after booting in it is prompting me to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04.
If I go ahead with the update will it upgrade to the full version of Ubuntu, which I doubt will run well on old hardware, or will I get to keep Lubuntu?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It will upgrade to Lubuntu 15.04, not Ubuntu 15.04. It will not replace LXDE with Unity (The differences between any flavor of Ubuntu is the desktop environment, so literally Ubuntu is the same as Lubuntu, only with Unity instead of LXDE.) Also, upgrading can have good effects, such as:

- Better security
- More features
- More useful stuff
- etc.

So, you should go upgrade it, and 14.10 is old and [end-of-life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life) now.

Here's an image to show it's old and [end-of-life](http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life):

[image: The "NOW" date is 19/12/2015]

Answer (score 11):

It will update to the newer version of Lubuntu.

The update process doesn't ever change your 'flavour' of Ubuntu. The upgrade path is very safe, but I'd always recommend making a backup of any important data or photos first.

Comment: Every time I upgraded my Ubuntu to a new flavor I had problems and had to reinstall from scratch so I wouldn't say it's very safe... (and I don't install so many stuff either).

Comment: @Shauiteh Flavors are like Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. Versions are like, 15.10, 16.04, 15.04, 14.10, 14.04, etc., not the opposite.